# Why viewport render (image and animation) are so different from the viewport in EEVEE

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

Do you have an idea regarding all the differences between viewport, viewport render image and viewport render animation?

When I hit render with the render panel I have the exactly same image than in viewport, but render time increases compared to the viewport render animation.

[image]

I've baked indirect lightning and all my settings are in attached files.

[image]

[image]
[image][image]

Comment: That's probably because you have set higher sample count in render than viewport.

Comment: Tks Dambacha, i don’t think so as i put same samples in both preview and render.
But it seems that the preview render doesn’t compute the filmic view transform, neither Exposure and gamma;(

I’m still looking for resolving this;)